# VLC and Totem crashes playing .wmv files

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, gstreamer, wmv

VLC & Totem crashes every time trying open .wmv movie (Rhythmbox also cant play .m4a music)
**ubuntu-restricted-*** installed

Tried:

- reinstall **ubuntu-restricted-***
- reinstall **gstreamer0.10-plugins-***
- **~/.gstreamer0.10** removed
- reinstall **vlc**

**ffmpeg** and all **gstreamer** and **vlc** addons from Software Center installed

vlc output:

```
maxim@maxim-Desktop:~$ vlc film.wmv 
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x11ea058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
maxim@maxim-Desktop:~$
```

System:

- Intel Core i7
- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- GTX 670 (official nvidia drivers)